# JavaFX - large controllers

Tags: javafx

I was searching for a long time but I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem of a javafx controller with a large number of elements. I have and application that is a native app, but we are doing some web style design and UI on it and it includes a number of overlays each with different text fields and combo boxes, like a stepped process while filling out a form. So I have 100+ @FXML notations like:

```
@FXML private TextField textField;
```

I would be super nice to tie all these together at least so I don't have to also set the value in the data model, it just seems really messy to have my model:

```
public class DataModel {
  private String text;

  public String getText() {
     return text;
  }

  public void setText() {
     this.text = text;
  }
}
```

And then have to set each field individually:

```
public class TextController {

   @FXML private TextField textField;

   private DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      // For the sake of example just pretend this does something!
      dataModel.setText(textField.getText());      

   }
}
```

I know there are bindings and maybe I read them wrong but it didn't seem like what I was looking for, can someone help me out or explain what I might be missing?

Comment: Can you re-state your question? Is it about large number of nodes in one controller, or about data model "tieing", or JavaFX binding confusion? What could you be missing for example?

Comment: Are you implementing a Controller and a DataModel for each TextField?